# ZingChart - How to place all "scale-y-n" objects to the left side of the chart?

Tags: zingchart

ZingChart seems to automatically place all (except the first one) scale-y objects to the right side of the chart.

Is there a way to place all y-axis to the left of the chart?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the placement attribute within your scale-y-n object. We were able to add an additional scale-y to the left using placement:default in the following example:

```js
var myChart = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "type":"line",
        "title":{
            "text":"Axis Placement",
            "adjust-layout":true
        },
        "plotarea":{
            "margins":"dynamic",
            "adjust-layout":true
        },
        "scale-x":{
            "label":{
                "text":"Scale X 1"
            }
        },
        "scale-y":{
            "values":"0:100:10",
            "label":{
                "text":"Scale Y 1"
            }
        },
        "scale-y-2":{
            "values":"0:1000:100",
            "placement":"default",
            "label":{
                "text":"Scale Y 2"
            }
        },
        "scale-y-3":{
            "values":"0:2000:200",
            "placement":"opposite",
            "label":{
                "text":"Scale Y 3"
            }
        },
        "plot":{
            
        },
        "series":[
            {
                "values":[69,68,54,48,70,74,98,70,72,68,49,69],
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y"
            },
            {
                "values":[510,530,470,600,480,520,750,520,550,470,600,480],
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-2"
            },
            {
                "values":[1542,1243,1630,1440,1031,1148,1055,1246,1048,1032,1038,1038],
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
};

zingchart.render({
  id: "myChart",
  height: "300px",
  width: "100%",
  data: myChart
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.zingchart.com/playground/lib/zingchart/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

This is a more simple way to move axis items instead of moving line, ticks, labels, etc. individually. "Default" is a tricky name for this value, but for Y axes, "default" means "to the left of the chart." For X axes, if you use the placement attribute, default means the bottom.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so if you have any questions about the attribute or this demo, please feel free to reach out.